# How to make a trialware?

Tags: windows, registry, trialware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i make my product as a trial version for 30 days ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525378/how-can-i-make-my-product-as-a-trial-version-for-30-days)

Dear all,

Recently I have developed a software for windows and I want to make a trial version out of it for advertisement. The trial version I have in mind should be runnable only for 30 days for example. I myself have an idea about saving the time of the system in a file or in the registry of windows, but changing the time of the system can also make my program confused.

What do you suggest ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525378/how-can-i-make-my-product-as-a-trial-version-for-30-days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using registry or any other recource on client system can make your software easy to crack
Instead of that you may write a licence server and your application  can check the licence over that server for each run..